# Copy object from hidden layer with Python

Tags: scripting, operator, layers

Is there a way to duplicate object located on inactive layer? `bpy.ops.object.duplicate()` doesn't do anything.

```
>>> D.objects
<bpy_collection[3], BlendDataObjects>

>>> C.object.layers[10] = True
>>> C.object.layers[0] = False
>>> C.object.select
True

>>> bpy.ops.object.duplicate()
{'FINISHED'}

>>> D.objects
<bpy_collection[3], BlendDataObjects>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [copy()](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78a_release/bpy.types.ID.html#bpy.types.ID.copy)  then link to the scene:

```
obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube'] #object you want to copy
dupe = obj.copy() # copy object
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(dupe) #links the copy yo the scene
```

Comment: Nice. Is it documented somewhere to ensure that it won't miss some links on copy?

Comment: Added the link to the answer. Objects are basically containers, and everything that is in one is put in the copy.

Comment: Do you know any good reading about these Blender containers? Why they should be linked to scene and what happens if they are not linked?

Comment: I was saying that Blender objects are like "containers". They hold data, like meshes, curves, etc. They have to be linked to a scene to be displayed. I don't know of any reading other than the manual and API.